# Keep track of Variable throughout debugging

Tags: javascript, debugging

There is a variable that is being created by a built-in library that gets passed in many functions as a parameter. I would like to keep track of that variable at any point during debugging. I am using the Chrome debugging tools. Some sort of mechanism so that even if I step into another function or file, I can type the name of the property and I can example it's properties(maybe even before it's created?). I want to do this because an object being passed into a function elsewhere isn't being created properly and I would like to see when/how it gets modified at each step. Thank you!

Here is some context to show you the level of complexity of tracking the variable.

Module 1 (let's say a.js)

```
...
this.Content = "some initial value that is modified probably"

render: function(r){
     ...
     m = this.Content;
     renderControl(a,m,b);
     ...
}

renderControl: function(r,m,c){
     ...
     Module2.Render(m);
     ...
}

....
```

Module 2 (let's say b.js)

```
...

Render: function(C){
...
    helper.doSomething(C);
...
}

...
```

Module 3 (let's say c.js)

```
...

doSomething: function(C){...};

...
```

So in Module 1 there is a property of the class (I assume) that is being created and changed somehow and then it is passed to Module 2 and Module 3 and back and forth. In C I get an error that the value passed (C) does not have a method that *should* be there (since Module 1).

Comment: is your variable mutable?

Comment: Pretty sure it is, it's an object in a built-in library.

Answer (score 0):

Ok if your variable is mutable so just set it to a global variable

var myGlobalVar = varIwantToTrack;

and you'll be able to see myGlobalVar anytime

Comment: It's inside a built-in library so is it possible to edit their code to include that? Also since there are multiple files would this work?

Comment: the debugger runs in the code runtime, so if you don't have the variable in the scope of the function being executed, the debugger cannot show its value.. It is not magical ahah And no you don't need to modify your lib because as you said the variable is passed to your functions, so you just need to assign the gobal variable in of those functions. According the multiple file issue, how to you load those files?

Comment: I edited my question to show more context. The files aren't mine, they are (I think) part of showing a UI control. So when a control is clicked, the libraries are loaded in order to show the control.

Comment: On another hand, if the debugger doesn't display the variable, that mean it isn't in the scope of the function being executed, which means the function being executed cannot access that variable, which means your variable can't be modified by that function, which means looking for that variable while it doesn't change doesn't worth it

Comment: ok so you include the files with script tags.. if so there is no pb, the global variable will be accessible from anyfile